# Is it possible to get pixelcolor(x,y) from covered(non active) window?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, colors, drawing

Is this possible even?

I am searching around the net but can't find a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most windows will handle `WM_PRINTCLIENT`, which can be used to create a bitmap of the client area even when the window is not visible.

Comment: i will search for this, thanks so much for valuable suggestion